# How to draw a simple straight line with HTML canvas as I move the mouse?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to draw a straight line along with my mouse movement. I got it working. But the issue is the `canvas.stroke` is redrawing lines over and over as I move the mouse. What is the workaround for this?
I just want one line not overlays of multiple lines.

Here is the `mousemove` listener:

```
canvasElement.onmousemove = (e) => {
            if (!started) return;
            context.beginPath();

            context.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply"; //<<<<
            context.globalAlpha = 0.05;
            context.lineWidth = size;
            context.strokeStyle = color;
            context.lineJoin = "round";
            context.lineCap = "round";
            context.moveTo(prvX, prvY);
            var dx = e.offsetX - prvX;
            var dy = e.offsetY - prvY;
            if (Math.abs(dx) > Math.abs(dy)) {
                context.lineTo(e.offsetX, prvY);
            } 
            context.stroke();
            context.closePath();
        };
```

Comment: Without seeing any of your code, my best guess is that your code isn't erasing the previous line before drawing a new line.

Comment: @abubakarutar is there a way to identify the previously drawn line?

Comment: @Nithur - what about clearing the context at the beginning of your mousemove handler?

Comment: @obscure I can't clear the context since I've other elements inside the context. I only want to remove the lines drawn along the current path.

Comment: Well thats not possible without destroying existing content on the canvas. You could store a backup of it's content and redraw that before drawing your line.

Comment: @obscure can you tell me how to do it without having any UI flicks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you drawn something e.g. a line over something that has previously drawn onto your canvas e.g. an image, the resulting pixeldata stored for your canvas is a combination of the old and the new data. That means you can't simply remove a semi-transparent line from it without destroying what was drawn below as well.

One solution would be using two independent canvases of the same size and at the same on-screen position. The canvas in the background holds your original image data and the canvas on top is used to draw the line. That way you can simply erase the top-canvas before drawing a new line.

In your case that might not work however as you're using a different `globalCompositeOperation` to draw the line. In this case I'd recommend storing the data of your canvas in a second canvas as soon as you've clicked on the 'painting' canvas for the first time. This way you can simply restore the data before drawing the line.

For example:

```js
let canvasElement = document.getElementById("canvas");
let context = canvasElement.getContext("2d");
let started = false;
let size = 7;
let color = "red"
let prvX = 0;
let prvY = 0;
let image = new Image();
let backupCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
let backupCanvasContext = backupCanvas.getContext("2d");
backupCanvas.width = canvasElement.width;
backupCanvas.height = canvasElement.height;
let backupCreated = false;
image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
image.onload = () => {
  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
}
image.src = `https://api.codetabs.com/v1/proxy?quest=https://picsum.photos/id/237/${canvasElement.width}/${canvasElement.height}`;

canvasElement.onmousedown = (e) => {
  if (!backupCreated) {
    backupCanvasContext.drawImage(canvasElement, 0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
    backupCreated = true;
  }
  started = true;
  prvX = e.offsetX;
  prvY = e.offsetY;
}

canvasElement.onmouseup = (e) => {
  started = false;
}

canvasElement.onmousemove = (e) => {
  if (!started) return;
  context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  context.drawImage(backupCanvas, 0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
  context.beginPath();

  context.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply"; //<<<<
  context.globalAlpha = 1;

  context.lineWidth = size;
  context.strokeStyle = color;
  context.lineJoin = "round";
  context.lineCap = "round";
  context.moveTo(prvX, prvY);
  var dx = e.offsetX - prvX;
  var dy = e.offsetY - prvY;
  if (Math.abs(dx) > Math.abs(dy)) {
    context.lineTo(e.offsetX, prvY);
  }
  context.stroke();
  context.closePath();
};
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for writing this. But what if I want to store multiple lines over the image?

Comment: In this case remove the `if (!backupCreated)` condition from the `onmousedown` handler to trigger a backup of your canvas each time you start a line.

Comment: Thank you. What if I need to fit images of various sizes into my canvas. When I use maxWidth and maxHeight attributes, the line is drawn a few inches above my mouse position. What's wrong?